# Get row id using jQuery while clicking a button in that row

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML table, each row have separate id. There is column in each row that contain a button. I can capture click event of those buttons. Is there any way to get the corresponding row id in click event of that button

Sample table is shown below.

```
<table>
 <tr id="1">
     <td>   <input type="image" id="Bttn_play" src="../../Content/images/play_button.png" name="image" /> </td>
     <td> test dat1a</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="2">
     <td>   <input type="image" id="Bttn_play" src="../../Content/images/play_button.png" name="image" /> </td>
     <td> test data2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I can capture click event of the button using following jQuery

```
$("#Bttn_play").live('click', function (event) {
  alert (row id);
  // how i get row id  corresponding to this button 
}
```

Comment: it's not a good practice to give same `id`'s to different entities..You can use `class` instead

Comment: And, also, outside of html5 it's not valid to use a numeral (0-9) as the first character of an `id` attribute.

Comment: @TheSuperTramp . then how can i capture click event of those buttons using a single jquery? I am generating this table dynamically.I think id is require to capture events

Comment: see [my answer, below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339942/get-row-id-using-jquery-while-clicking-a-button-in-that-row/5339961#5339961), you can use a `class` (`$('.Bttn_play')`) to capture events, or just use the element type (`$('input[type="image"]')`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `closest()`:

```
$("#Bttn_play").live('click',function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});
```

It's worth noting that a duplicate `id` is invalid, an `id` **must** be unique within the document, you should convert `id='Bttn_play'` to `class='Bttn_play'` (and modify the jQuery selector to: `$('.Bttn_play')`).

---

**Edited** in response to OP's question (in comments to question):

> how can i capture click event of those buttons using a single jquery? I am generating this table dynamically.I think id is require to capture events

To select an element, using jQuery, it's possible to use the `class` attribute (as above), or the element-type. In this instance, to select an `input` element of `type="image"`:

```
$('input[type="image"]')
```

Or:

```
$('input:image')
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).
- [`:image` selector](http://api.jquery.com/image-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [jQuery .parent() method](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .parent()
>   method allows us to search through the
>   parents of these elements in the DOM
>   tree and construct a new jQuery object
>   from the matching elements.

```
$("#Bttn_play").live('click', function (event) {

    var rowID = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
});
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H9rpp/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#Bttn_play").live('click', function (event) {
  alert ($(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));

}
```